# Need to reboot after waking from sleep mode on my windows 8.1 tablet

Tags: windows-8.1, crash, sleep, hibernate, npapi

I searched and tried much but it does little help to my problem.

When I put my tablet pc aside and it will sleep after 5 mins. This is what I expected by setting power config.

However if I leave it sleeping for more than 20 mins, I may (not everytime, likely 30% of tries) encounter the following issues:

1. One of my program based on Qt5.4.1 freezes and won't response. It is a web-browser-like, compiled on Windows7 program which displays a flash game. It watches https with FiddlerCore. If I terminate it from task manager, It won't be started.
2. If I run chrome it shows "flash plugin crashes". I can still open webpages. I can start other programs.
3. If I press power key (which I set it to make pc into sleep), the screen turns black. And If I press again, the screen lighted but still shows black only. I can touch the screen and it shows the touch traces. But nothing will work unless I force shut down the pc by pressing down the power key for 10 secs.
4. If I press down the power key for several seconds while the screen is still on, it shows me "slide down to shutdown the pc". However, it won't work. It then turns to the lighted black screen.

So I need to force reboot the device every time it happens.

Actually the program didn't crash. The display won't refresh and it won't receive my inputs. So I find no crash reports about it.
I don't know if it's a problem of flash plugin but actually, the flash plugins are different. Qt uses the firefox plugin.

I can't find any choices in power config about turning off HDD while sleep.

Any ideas of avoiding this?

P.S. Are there possibilities that I installed both NPAPI and PPAPI version of Adobe Flash?

Answer (score 0):

Your PC may be going into Hibernation, which was the bane of my existence when I was testing third-generation Core processors at Intel Jones Farm.

I'd suggest you disable Hibernation after enabling High Performance. To turn on High performance, open Power Options by swiping in from the right edge of the screen, tapping Search (or if you're using a mouse, pointing to the upper-right corner of the screen, moving the mouse pointer down, and then clicking Search), entering Power Options in the search box, tapping or clicking Settings, and then tapping or clicking Power Options. Tap or click Show additional plans, and then choose High performance.

Then, in the High Performance Plan, disable hard drive spindown.

Also, fast startup is turned in by default in Windows, a setting designed to help your PC start up faster after shutdown. Windows does this by saving system info to a file upon shutdown ('Hibernation') so when you start your PC again, Windows uses that system info to resume your PC instead of restarting it. That's the design; sometimes if causes problems.

Therefore, please disable Fast Startup by opening a Command Prompt window with `Start | CMD | POWERCFG /hibernate off`

If that does not resolve it, run `POWERCFG /a > POWER.TXT` and post the result here.

Comment: I agree with your points but I do need those power-saving things since I use it as a mobile device...

Comment: Once we've isolated what solves the problem, then we can reconfigure for power saving.